# Get media links from urls, not with api.user_timeline / Tweepy-Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Tweepy doesn't support bookmarks. I have saved my bookmark links in a text file (about 400 links). I want to get the media links of these tweets. I can do it for tweets from timeline but while pulling tweets from timeline, tweepy saves additional info. How can I do the same for manually added tweets? Like how can I import links as *https://twitter.com/xyz123/status/12344567902367* and make tweepy work with them?

my code works right now, but it needs links from a file. I got these links with a chrome extension but still, I wonder if there is a better way.

```
import API_Tokens as t
from tweepy import OAuthHandler, API
import os
import wget


def main():
    file1 = open("bookmarks.txt", "r")
    try:
        os.mkdir('bookmarks')
        os.chdir('bookmarks')
    except:
        os.chdir('bookmarks')

    api = authenticate()
    getTweets(api, file1)


def getTweets(api, file1):
    count = 0

    while True:
        count += 1
        full_twt = file1.readline()
        id = full_twt[full_twt.find("status") + 7:]  # id of a tweet starts from "status/"
        tweet = api.get_status(id)  # fetch the tweet
        media = tweet.entities.get('media', [])  # get the media info

        if len(media) > 0:
            wget.download((media[0]['media_url']))  # download the image if media exists

    file1.close()
    return all_tweets


def authenticate():     # developer access
    auth = OAuthHandler(t.CONSUMER_KEY, t.CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(t.ACCESS_TOKEN, t.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    api = API(auth)
    return api


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you want feedback on.

Comment: just added it @RJAdriaansen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're now passing one api call per tweet. You can reduce the number of calls with [statuses_lookup](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_status#API.statuses_lookup) which takes a list of up to 100 tweet ids per request.

```
with open("bookmarks.txt", "r") as f:
    l = f.readlines() #create list of tweet urls
    l = [int(i.split('/')[-1]) for i in l] #extract tweet ids
    
n = 100
chunks = [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)] #split list in chunks

all_tweets = []

for i in chunks:
    tweets = api.statuses_lookup(i) #retrieve tweets
    all_tweets = all_tweets + tweets #store tweets in list
```

Comment: Thanks, this optimizes the code well.